# Regex find first occurance of either of two strings C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find whether "AND" and/or "OR" exist in my string and if so, replace the first occurrence with "WHERE".

**Examples**

`AND item = 'blah'` **AND would be replaced with WHERE.**

`AND item = 'blah' OR product = 'foo'` **AND would be replaced with WHERE.**

`OR item = 'blah OR item = 'foo'` **First occurrence of OR would be replaced with WHERE.**

**If neither AND nor OR exist then leave string as is.**

I have the following which works if the string contains both AND and OR, but if the string ONLY contains AND it does not work because y is equal to -1 and `x < y` is always going to be false. It's been doing my head, plus its late here, any help from someone currently charged with caffeine would be greatly appreciated.

```
private string ReplaceFilter(string filter)
{
    int x = filter.IndexOf("AND");
    int y = filter.IndexOf("OR");
    string regEsc = (x != -1 && x < y) ? "AND" : "OR";

    var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(regEsc));
    return regex.Replace(filter, "WHERE", 1);
}
```

**EDIT** In response to @Luaan, I am aware of SQL injection and have taken the proper steps by adding Parameters the correct way, however I have excluded that part of the code, because it is has no relevance to my question. At this stage I just need to build the string.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you really trying to build queries like this? Aren't you worried about SQL injection?

Comment: So if someone wants to buy a `PANDA`, he will buy a `PWHEREA`?

Comment: @Luaan At this stage I am only building a string, not creating a SQL command yet

Comment: Yeah, but why? Just use some composable form instead of working with strings. It's not really that hard even if you start from scratch, and there's plenty of libraries that allow you to work with SQL queries in a composable way (like Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL, but also considerably smaller-scope projects). You're creating more problems than you're solving by slapping strings together - just use the proper types instead of primitives.

Comment: Trust me, as much as I would love to use LINQ to SQL, in my case I cannot. You would need to understand the complexity of my search functionality as to why I need to use "primitive" methods of string manipulation. The user(s) are allowed to input various types of search patterns which require me to manipulate strings. I implement LINQ as much as I can in my apps and wish I could do the same here, but it is not the case. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex

```
AND|OR
```

to search for an AND or an OR and then use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) overload of the regex `Replace` method as follows to ensure you only replace the first one:

```
var output = new Regex("AND|OR").Replace(input, "WHERE", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match on this:

```
^(AND|OR)(.*)
```

It will search for `AND` or `OR` at the start of the `string`. You can simply replace the first capture with `where`:

```
string input = "AND x=AND;";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(AND|OR)(.*)", "where $2");
```

If you don't want to match only where the expression starts with `AND` or `OR`, omit the `^`:

```
(AND|OR)(.*)
```

Comment: This will only work if the string starts with either AND or OR. As far as I understood it, the AND and OR may appear anywhere in the string

Comment: Not according to the samples, but okay, then OP could just remove the `^`. Updated.

Comment: No, in that case all ocurrences of AND and OR would be replaced.

Comment: @Georg No, the `.*` will capture and protect the rest of the input.